# The Luz Bone has the size of a kernel of barley?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

It is [said](https://theisraelbible.com/what-did-moses-actually-see-when-god-showed-him-his-back/):

> The Midrash in Bereishit Raba describes this bone as a minuscule bone
> from the spine, about the size of a single barley grain, and almost
> cubic in shape.

See also [this](https://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luz_(bone)) article on Wikipedia.

Where is it mentioned exactly, that the luz bone has the size of a single barley grain?

Comment: Where is "It" said?

Comment: @Shmuel 
it is written here https://theisraelbible.com/what-did-moses-actually-see-when-god-showed-him-his-back/  also in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luz_(bone) question edited

Comment: The [Hebrew wiki article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%96) attributes this view to R. Aharon Berakhyah of Modena, citing מעבר יבק, חלק שפת אמת, פרק ו, מהדורת וילנא דף צח.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find the particulair Midrash in Bereishis Rabbah. But, the Midrash in [Koheles Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.5?lang=bi&p2=Kohelet_Rabbah.12.5.1&lang2=bi) (the Midrash on Ecclessiastes) explains that the luz bone is the **nut-sized bone** at the top of the spinal column.

> “The almond tree will blossom” – Rabbi Levi said: This is the
> nut-sized bone at the top of the spinal column. Hadrian, may his bones
> be crushed and his name expunged, asked Rabbi Yehoshua ben Ḥananya; he
> said to him: ‘From where does a person blossom in the future?’ He said
> to him: ‘From the nut-sized bone at the top of the spinal column.’
> [Hadrian] said to him: ‘Show me.’ What did [Rabbi Yehoshua] do? He
> brought him the nut-sized bone at the top of the spinal column. He
> placed it in water, but it did not dissolve; in fire, but it did not
> burn; in a mill, but it was not ground. He placed in on an anvil and
> struck it with a hammer. The anvil split, the hammer split, but it was
> to no avail.